# Properly removing elements from linked-list? Memory errors with pointers

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, valgrind

I'm implementing a hashtable that has a remove_entry function as well as a clear_table function. Right now I'm getting memory read errors pertaining to the remove_entry function. And help would be greatly appreciated

These are my structures:

```
typedef struct bucket {
   char *key;
   void *value;
   struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
   int key_count;
   int table_size;
   void (*free_value)(void *);
   Bucket **buckets;
} Table;
```

Here's my function:

```
int remove_entry(Table * table, const char *key){
    unsigned int hc = 0;
    Bucket *curr_b;
    Bucket *next_b;

    if(table == NULL || key == NULL){
        return FAIL;
    } else {
        hc = hash_code(key)%(table->table_size);
        if(table->buckets[hc] != NULL){
            curr_b = table->buckets[hc];

            /*Check the buckets in linked list*/
            while(curr_b != NULL){
                next_b = curr_b->next;

                if(strcmp(curr_b->key,key) == 0){
                    free(curr_b->key);
                    if(table->free_value != NULL){
                        table->free_value(curr_b->value);
                    }
                    free(curr_b);
                    curr_b = NULL;
                    table->key_count--;
                    return SUCC;
                } else {
                    curr_b = next_b;
                }
            }
            return FAIL;
        }
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

The memory leaks come after removing an entry, and trying to read the table after. I don't think I removed things right.

Memory errors:

Can't figure out how to copy/paste from terminal, so they all say things like

```
Invalid read of size __
Address ____ is __ bytes inside a block of size ___ free'd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the case where `table->buckets[hc]` is the bucket you free.

Right before `free(curr_b->key);` add:

```
if(curr_b == table->buckets[hc]) {
    table->buckets[hc] = next_b;
}
```

As it is now, you free a bucket, but `table->buckets[hc]` still points to it. So the next time you read it you are reading free'ed memory. Thus the error.

Also, you need to keep track of the *previous* bucket so you can point the previous bucket to the next bucket when you remove a bucket.