# How data structures are organized on heap

Tags: c, linked-list

Right now my structures look like this for a project I have to do:

```
typedef struct bucket {
   char *key;
   void *value;
   struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
   int key_count;
   int table_size;
   void (*free_value)(void *);
   Bucket **buckets;
} Table;
```

Can someone please explain to me how the structures are organized? Like I want to know what `Bucket **buckets` is pointing to. This data format is supposed to be a Table that has a linked list of buckets.

A diagram would help.

thank you.

Comment: Was this code given to you, or did you come up with it?

Comment: buckets will point to whatever bucket you tell it to point to.

Comment: This code was given to us for our project and we have to implement things with it

Comment: I answered a question this just morning with the same data structures. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620579/properly-removing-elements-from-linked-list-memory-errors-with-pointers/19620688#19620688 You best bet is to read about hash tables on wikipedia.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists

Comment: I can see two options for the `Bucket **buckets` use. The first is that it is a dynamically allocated array storing a specific number of `Bucket` lists. The other is that the "double pointer" is used to point to the head of a unique list of buckets.

Comment: thanks fo the  replies

Comment: Just a style remark. I would not use `typedef` for anything else than to opacify the type (if it can be defined in various locations, the appropriate one being loaded depending on some config flags) or for portability reasons (Windows code loves to do so, like in the socket code).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Table` object has :

(a) two members holding size info: `key_count` and `table_size`

(b) a function pointer `free_value` that takes no argument and returns nothing. Presumably, it does something with the other members of `Table`

(c) and to answer your question: `Bucket **buckets;` is an array of pointers, each of which points to a linked list of `Bucket`'s.

The link @Charlie has added in the comments should teach you more about hash tables.

The idea is simple: You want to store a bunch of `values` in a table, but you don't like to search through the whole table to find an entry. Given `N` values, that costs you `O(N)` (think of a naive table as a single linked list).

You figure that you could "hash" this `value` via a custom function known as a "hash function" to generate a "`key`" and store the `key-value` pair instead.

This way, when you need to lookup the `value`, you find its hash (i.e., the `key`) and that takes you to a linked list of `Bucket`'s. Each `Bucket` in this list contains a `key-value` pair. You traverse through the list until you find your value.

If your custom hash function is intelligent enough to not hash several values to the same `key`, you can reduce your lookup time to something much smaller than `O(N)`.

Think of it as spreading your `values` into several single linked lists, and being able to know which list you want to traverse in `O(1)` time via your hash function.

**Edit:** I just noticed that your `Bucket` struct has a key and value field. What I've explained above uses a `key` to get to a linked list of `values`. So, my notion of the list doesn't require the `key` as a member since its really just a chain of values.

I'm wondering why you'd need the `Bucket` to hold a redundant key member when it has a next pointer.

Comment: so would I initialize buckets as: table->buckets = calloc(table_size, sizeof(Bucket)); ?

Comment: Nope, each entry in `table->buckets` is a "pointer to `Bucket`", not the actual `Bucket`, so if you want to allocate memory for these pointers in advance, it'd be:
`table->buckets = calloc(table_size, sizeof(Bucket*));`

What do these pointers point to? Garbage! So, you need to `nullptr` initialize each of them via a loop or use memset. I don't see why you'd create memory for the actual `Bucket`'s that these pointers point to w/o inserting data.

Comment: Ok I see. This is confusing. So my array of bucket pointers, buckets, is an array like: Buckets[ARRAY_LENGTH]; and each index in the array starting from zero points to the head of a linked list, correct?

Comment: Yes, perfect! Double pointers are confusing at the start - its easy to think of `char**` as an array of strings, which really is an array of pointers, each of which points to the start of a string. Only thing is that you don't know ARRAY_LENGTH at compile time, and hence have to use *alloc.

Comment: Right we are supposed to initialize them to null to begin with and then later on in the code do stuff with them

Comment: Ok now I understand. And lastly, I need to set each bucket node in every linked list, that is present in every array index, to null? Ok I see

Comment: But wait, couldn't I also do: buckets[table_size]; ?

Comment: Umm, nope. All you've done is allocate memory for an array of pointers to `Bucket`, and set each of them to `nullptr`.
When you go on to insert an entry into the table, you'll change one of the `nullptr`'s to point to a newly created `Bucket` element (which resides in the heap). And when you do this, you should initialize `next` in that `Bucket` to `nullptr` again.

Comment: Well, you don't know `table_size` at compile time. I'm guessing that's something the user enters. So, you can't use a static array (i.e, an array who's size is known at compile time)